# How is "expected approximation ratio" defined in cases when the expected value of the optimal solution is known?

Tags: approximation

Consider an approximation algorithm which does better than $f(n)$, in expectation. Suppose we know that $\mathbb{E}(OPT)=g(n)$.

Given that we use the convention of "larger divided by smaller" for approximation ratios, can we say that the "expected approximation ratio" is better than $g(n)/f(n)$?

The other possibility is that expected approximation ratio is defined as the expectation of the optimal solution divided by the approximation.

In other words, there are two possibilities: one, we compute $\frac{\mathbb{E}(OPT)}{\mathbb{E}(APPROX)}$, or, we could compute $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{OPT}{APPROX}\right)$. Which quantity would be the "expected approximation ratio"?

Comment: Usually the instance is deterministic, that is, OPT is constant. The randomness only comes from the approximation algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In some problems, for example: [optimal stopping problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20theory%20of,or%20minimise%20an%20expected%20cost.&text=A%20key%20example%20of%20an%20optimal%20stopping%20problem%20is%20the%20secretary%20problem.), the input is random, so we measure the expected optimal cost.

Comment: Yes, @InuyashaYagami is right. The problem I am working on has a different optimal solution depending on the input, and I computed an upper bound on the expected value of the optimal solution across all inputs. Additionally, my approximation algorithm is deterministic on a given input, but I take the expectation across all inputs.

Comment: I am not an expert at this. However, I think both measures are the right ways. However, the first one: $\frac{\mathbb{E}(OPT)}{\mathbb{E}(APPROX)}$ is typically used. For example, see [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/ipco17/ipco-talk3.pdf). It could be because it is easier to analyze than the second one.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!  I have been unable to find any papers so this is very helpful.